# Stack Navigator drawer icon click drawer not opening but when slide it opening

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want the drawer to open when i click on the left icon; here is my code :

```
const stackNav = StackNavigator({
  Main : {
    screen: MainScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: "Easy Billing",
      headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
          <IOSIcon name="ios-menu" size={30} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
      headerStyle: { } 
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import { DrawerActions, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

and then:

```
const stackNav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Main : {
    screen: MainScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: "Easy Billing",
      headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer()); }}>
          <IOSIcon name="ios-menu" size={30} onPress={() => { navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer()); }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
      headerStyle: { } 
    })
  }
});
```

You can't display the drawer while you are using a stackNavigator; that is why I used the createDawerNavigator variable.
Notice that the `DrawerNavigator` and the `StackNavigator` are deprecated, use `createDrawerNavigator` and `createStackNavigator` instead.

Comment: hi Steve Nossse its working by when slide , but that drawer icon and header not displayed could u help me

Comment: May be because on the headerStyle that return null ? Remove it  and try again

Answer (score 1):

The defaults for opening, closing and toggle the drawer are:

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
```

you can use these in the onPress prop of a button.
like so,
`<Button onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.openDrawer(); }} />`